# Django - 'myapp' vs 'myapp.apps.myappConfig' in settings.py Installed Apps

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, app-config, django-apps

I know this might sound stupid but I was just wondering what's the difference if I just type 'myapp' instead of 'myapp.apps.myappConfig' in my Installed Apps list. Is it something related to models or what?

Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use `myapp.apps.myappConfig`, then you are explicitly telling Django to use that app config class.

Changing the app config class lets you change the behaviour of the application, for example, when you use the admin app, you can use `django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig` which autodiscovers apps, or `django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig`, which does not.

If you just use `myapp`, then Django will try to use `default_app_config`. If that isn't set, then it will use the default `AppConfig`.

A lot of the time, there isn't any customisation in `myappConfig`, or `default_app_config` is set, so you'll get the same behaviour whichever style you use in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Ever since `AppConfig` was added in Django 1.7, the recommendation has been to use ``myapp.apps.myappConfig`because it's explicit, and avoid using`default_app_config`.

However, in practice, it seems that users have preferred the simplicity of using `myapp`. Therefore, there's [an open pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/12310) which will remove `default_app_config`, and automatically select the app config class when there is only one.